# Probability that a student knows the answer

Tags: probability

The Probality that a student knows the correct answer to a multiple choice question is 2/3 . If the student does not know the  answer , then the student guesses the answer . The probality of the guessed answer being correct is 1/4 . Given that the student has answered the questions correctly , the conditional probability that the student knows the correct answer is ***_***

I started solving it . But I'm stuck .

Let

a = student knows the  correct answer

b = guessed answer is correct

P(a)=2/3  P(a')=1/3

P(b)=1/4  P(b')=3/4

Let c = answered all questions correctly

I guess

P(c)=P(a)+P(a').P(b)

P(c)=(2/3) +((1/3).(1/4))

P(c) = 3/4

TO find

P(a/c)=P(a n c)/p(c)

I dont know how to find p(a n c) . Please elaborate and Help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define the events as:

\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=& \mbox{Student knows the correct answer} \\
C &=& \mbox{Student answered correctly.} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

You are asked to find a *conditional* probability, $P(A \mid C)$. We can use Bayes' Theorem to calculate it:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A \mid C) &=& \dfrac{P(C \mid A)P(A)}{P(C \mid A)P(A) + P(C \mid A^c)P(A^c)} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{1 \times \frac{2}{3}}{1 \times \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{3}} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{8}{9}
\end{eqnarray*}

Note:

1. $P(C \mid A) = 1$ because, given that the student knows the answer, the answer must be correct.
2. Event $A^c$ is "the student guessed" because he guesses if he doesn't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

p(a n c) will be the probability **that he knows the correct answer and has answered correctly** which should be (2/3 * 1)

Comment: In (2/3 * 1)  , how do you consider it is 1 for he has answered correctly . Because P(getting correct answer)=3/4

Comment: because if he knows the answer than it is correct with prob. 1, how could the prob. be not 1 if he knows the answer correctly?

Answer (score 0):

2/3 of the questions he will know and answer correctly.
Of the remaining 1/3, the student will guess 1/4 of them correctly.

So, 2/3 + (1/4 x 1/3) = 3/4 of questions answered correctly

1/4 x 1/3 = 1/12, which is the percentage of questions guessed correctly.

What percentage of the total 3/4 is that 1/12?

To find out, just divide: 
So, the probability that he guessed: (1/12)/(3/4) = 1/9
and the probability that he knows the answer is: (11/12)/(3/4) = 8/9
or you could just do 1 - 1/9 = 8/9