# Probability that a student guesses an answer (for multiple independent instances)?

Tags: probability

I read this question recently: [Probability that a student knows the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944034/probability-that-a-student-knows-the-answer)

Putting this in reverse, if the student guessed the answer then the probability would be:

\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=& \mbox{Student knows the correct answer} \\
C &=& \mbox{Student answered correctly.} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
GIVEN: Probability that the student knows the answer is 2/3

GIVEN: Probability that the student guesses an answer and is correct is 1/4

Finding $P(A^C \mid C)$ using Bayes' theorem:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A^C \mid C) &=& \dfrac{P(C \mid A^C )P(A^C )}{P(C \mid A)P(A) + P(C \mid A^c)P(A^c)} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{4}}{1 \times \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{3}} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{9}
\end{eqnarray*}

So my question is, if the student did a 2nd or $nth$ test and it had the same question, how would you calculate the probability that the student guessed the answer for both tests assuming he got the answer right on both times?

I'm assuming that the student doesn't know the results (or even remember the previous test) so he's basically just getting lucky doing the same guess and being correct each time he does the test question. So since each test taken is independent of each other, does that mean that everything can essentially be taken to the power of 2 for two tests or to the $nth$ power for $n$ number of tests taken?

\begin{eqnarray*}
D &=& \mbox{Student knows the correct answer for n questions} \\
E &=& \mbox{Student answered correctly for n questions} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$P(D)=P(A)^n ?$$
$$P(E)=P(C)^n ?$$

Then you could follow through that the probability that the student is guessing the answer, after we witnessed them being all correct, can be calculated as:
$$P(D^C \mid E)=P(A^C \mid C)^n=(\dfrac{1}{9})^n$$

Right?

EDIT: Ignore $(D)$ and $(E)$ for now (if that is helpful) and do in terms of $(A)$ and $(C)$ for two tests (or more). Here's some helpful visualization:
[image: Tree diagram]

So the blue circle shows the probability path I'm trying to find out.

Rephrasing a little better: **What is the probability that the student is guessing the answer for 2 tests (or $n$ tests) after witnessing the event C (that he answered correctly)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not that simple. You have to use Bayes' Theorem again. Firstly, since all answers are made independently of each other, given that the student is guessing, the probability of answering all $n$ questions correctly is $P(E \mid D^c) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n$. So,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(D^c \mid E) &=& \dfrac{P(E \mid D^c)P(D^c)}{P(E \mid D^c)P(D^c) + P(E \mid D)P(D)} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n \times \frac{1}{3}}{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n \times \frac{1}{3} + 1 \times \frac{2}{3}} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{1 + 2\times 4^n}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: The algebra looks a bit off, shouldn't it be:
$$= \dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n \times \frac{1}{3}}{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n \times \frac{1}{3} + 1 \times \frac{2}{3}} \\

=\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n }{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n  + 2 } $$

Comment: Are you sure that's right? I understand that my original proposition doesn't hold because each test taken is independent of the other. Perhaps for the sake of clarity, ignore $(D)$ and $(E)$ and we just stick with the original events $(A)$ and $(C)$. What would that look like for two consecutive tests?

 I also added a helpful tree pic for visualization in the OP.

Comment: @user155876 Your value and mine are the same. Just multiply your numerator and denominator by $4^n$. Does that fix everything?

Comment: Ahh okay. So just to clarify, the probability that the student is guessing (and getting the answer right) for $n$ tests will be $\dfrac{1}{1 + 2\times 4^n}$? So if I wanted to know what the probability was 3 tests, it would be $\dfrac{1}{1 + 2\times 4^3}$ yes? If not then I'm confused, because technically you'd have to run Bayes' Theorem for each test taken yeah?

Comment: @user155876 That's exactly right. It works for any $n$. And if $n=1$ It gives $1/9$ which you calculated as part of your question.